# Complexity upper bound using Raichaudhury equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity

Can one find the relationship between Quantum complexity and gravity by employing Raichaudhury's equation, utilized by Hawking and Penrose in proving their black hole singularity theorems, to calculate the upper bound of quantum complexity and thereby demonstrate that general relativity would be valid until complexity reaches its maximum by using Nielsen et al.'s work, which relates differential geometry, namely geodesic, to calculate the quantum complexity of states?

Comment: You may want to turn the question into a few sentences, it is very hard to parse. So what you are asking is what the link is between the Raychaudhuri equation and quantum complexity measures?

Comment: What I am asking is can Raichaudhury equation be used to show that their exists a generic upper bound on the complexity of any Quantum state

Comment: Something like what Adam Brown does for lower bounds https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.05724  ?

Comment: Seems like it. I wonder if their is any any conceptual error in using the technique to calculate the upper bound.